# Can I modify JSON requests with PowerShell v2?

Tags: json, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to prettify some JSON responses using PowerShell v2 (which my version doesn't have the useful ConverFrom-Json or Invoke-RestMethod cmdlets) so I can output the response to at the very least a CSV file.  I can use that to search through the data, but am having a hard time with the Export-CSV cmdlet to get the right format.

Is this possible to do?

My basic code is this:

```
[string]$url = "http://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/info/browsers/webdriver"
enter code here`$temp = "SauceLabsSupportedEnvs.csv"
# Accessing the REST API at Sauce Labs and downloading to a file
$json = (New-Object Net.Webclient).DownloadString($url)
```

What I want to do is get the $json response into something usable.  What I have tried and not been able to get to work, are these two:

Either trying to convert on the delimiter
    $json | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "{" -NoTypeInformation | Out-File $temp

Or just exporting the data be default
    $json | Export-Csv -Path $temp

Both just give me the type information in the CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my own in PowerShell V1.0, or in PowerShell V2.0 I convert JSON responses to XML and then exploit it. This is also interesting in PowerShell 3.0 when the JSON is too big.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.ServiceModel.Web, System.Runtime.Serialization

$utf8 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8    
function Write-String
{
  PARAM([Parameter()]$stream,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$string)

  PROCESS
  {
    $bytes = $utf8.GetBytes($string)
    $stream.Write( $bytes, 0, $bytes.Length )
  }  
}

function Convert-JsonToXml
{
  PARAM([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string[]]$json)

  BEGIN
  { 
    $mStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream 
  }

  PROCESS
  {
    $json | Write-String -stream $mStream
  }

  END
  {
    $mStream.Position = 0
    try
    {
       $jsonReader = [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonReaderWriterFactory]::CreateJsonReader($mStream,[System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas]::Max)
       $xml = New-Object Xml.XmlDocument
       $xml.Load($jsonReader)
       $xml
    }
    finally
    {
       $jsonReader.Close()
       $mStream.Dispose()
    }
  }
}

function Convert-XmlToJson
{
  PARAM([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][Xml]$xml)

  PROCESS
  {
    $mStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
    $jsonWriter = [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonReaderWriterFactory]::CreateJsonWriter($mStream)
    try
    {
      $xml.Save($jsonWriter)
      $bytes = $mStream.ToArray()
      [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($bytes,0,$bytes.Length)
    }
    finally
    {
      $jsonWriter.Close()
      $mStream.Dispose()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is Write-String in this case?  I've tried this out but I get an error about that not being a recognized cmdlet. A Google Search on the term did not bring anything up.

Comment: Sorry, I miss a part or the code, let's see the edit.